# Issue with Relationship Mapping in Spring Boot Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller, objectmapper, mockmvc

Description:

https://github.com/Patryk241194/REST-API-library/blob/main/src/test/java/com/kodilla/library/controller/BookCopyControllerTestSuite.java

I'm facing an issue with relationship mapping in Spring Boot controllers. I have a project structured as follows:

```
project-root
|-- main
|   |-- java
|   |   |-- com.kodilla.library
|   |       |-- controller
|   |       |-- domain
|   |       |-- dto
|   |       |-- error
|   |       |-- mapper
|   |       |-- repository
|   |       |-- service
|-- test
|   |-- java
|   |   |-- com.kodilla.library
|   |       |-- controller
|   |       |-- repository
```

In this project, I'm testing the controllers in the com.kodilla.library.controller package. My issue lies in the relationship mapping between entities, specifically, BookCopy and BookTitle. When I create objects using controllers, the relationship is not being established correctly, resulting in the TITLE_ID being null in bookCopy instances.

Here's a simplified example of the problem:

BookCopyControllerTestSuite.java:

```
@Test
void testCreateBookCopy() throws Exception {
    // Creating a BookTitle
    mockMvc.perform(post("/api/booktitles")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(bookTitleDto)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

    // Creating a BookCopy
    mockMvc.perform(post("/api/bookcopies")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(bookCopyDto)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

    // The problem: bookCopyDto.getTitleId() is null in the controller
    // but should be populated based on the relationship with bookTitleDto.
}
```

In the above test, bookCopyDto.getTitleId() should be populated based on the relationship with bookTitleDto. However, it remains null. The thing is that the service layer correctly handles this relationship, but it breaks in the controllers.

Question:

How can I ensure that the relationship mapping works correctly in the Spring Boot controllers?
Is there a specific configuration or method that I should be using to set the TITLE_ID correctly when creating bookCopy objects via the controller?
Additional Note: I have also tested the repository layer, and the relationship mapping works correctly there. The issue appears to be specific to the controller implementations.

Any help or guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: There are hundreds of reasons why this would not be working as you expect it to, but you're going to need to include a lot more code, at least the controller, service, repository, and model with all applied annotations

Comment: @lane.maxwell I added a link to github in the description, due to my mistake the link didn't work before.

Comment: I ran your tests and got the desired behavior by simply adding @NoArgsConstructor to both of your DTOs (BookTitleDto and BookCopyDto). It looked like you extracted that behavior into your setup method, and your `testCreateBookCopy` is now just doing a GET.  But, by adding those annotations, all is working